# How to partition a table based on a pattern(in this case an increasing sub sequence) that is found in a column in presto sql

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am encountering the following problem. I have a table T, in which there is column named offset which will always be a collection of increasing sub sequences of integers beginning with zero.

```
Table T:

**row_num, offset ,col_1, col_2, col_3 ....**
     1       0
     2      10
     3      22
     4       32
     5       0
     6       0
     7       12
     8       32 
     9       44
```

I want to partition the table based on offset column such that the rows belonging to each strictly increasing subsequence are put into one partition. In the above example rows [1,2,3,4] , [0], [0,12,32,44] are the partitions that i am looking for. How do i proceed or is this even possible in sql?

I tried using lead and lag partition functions, the idea was to come up with an auxiliary column which stores partition numbers and then group by the resulting table based on this column. But i believe such an effort would require the loop functionality which i don't think exists in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a running sum function that increased by 1 whenever a zero offset value is found over the increasing of row_num:

```
select row_num, offset,
  sum(case when offset = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by row_num) prt
from table_name
```

The output of this query:

```
row_num   offset    prt
1         0         1
2         10        1
3         22        1
4         32        1
5         0         2
6         0         3
7         12        3
8         32        3
9         44        3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to identify rows that satisfy a pattern. In your case, you can define a pattern of increasing values of the column `offset`:

```
WITH t(row_num, offset) AS (
    VALUES
             (1, 0),
             (2, 10),
             (3, 22),
             (4, 32),
             (5, 0),
             (6, 0),
             (7, 12),
             (8, 32),
             (9, 44)
)
SELECT row_num, offset, partition FROM t
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY row_num
        MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS partition
        ALL ROWS PER MATCH
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
        PATTERN (START UP*)
        DEFINE UP AS offset > PREV(offset)
    )
```

What the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause says in the query above is:

- Find a sequence of rows (ordered by `row_num`) that matches the pattern `START UP*`. The `START` element should appear once and the `UP` element should appear zero or more times following it. `START` and `UP` are arbitrary names to represent rows in the sequence. `START` is defined implicitly and it matches any row, while `UP` is defined as a row whose `offset` column has a value larger than the `offset` column of the previous row in the sequence (`DEFINE UP AS offset > PREV(offset)`)
- Compute an output column named `partition` whose value is a synthetic number associated with each match. (`MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS partition`)
- Output all the input rows with the `partition` column annotation. (`ALL ROWS PER MATCH`)

The query produces:

```
 row_num | offset | partition
---------+--------+-----------
       1 |      0 |         1
       2 |     10 |         1
       3 |     22 |         1
       4 |     32 |         1
       5 |      0 |         2
       6 |      0 |         3
       7 |     12 |         3
       8 |     32 |         3
       9 |     44 |         3
(9 rows)
```

For more details, please see:

- https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html
- https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html

Note that this functionality is only available in [Trino](https://trino.io/) and Athena version 3, which is based on Trino.